# Spark Aggregator with Array as Input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I am migrating some Scala Spark UDAFs from UserDefinedAggregateFunction to Aggregator. One of them takes as input Array[String], and I am getting a strange exception when executing the Aggregator in a local test. I have reduced my code to a very basic Aggregator, but I'm still getting this error when reading Arrays. I don't have a problem with other input types.

The simplified example is as follows:

```
  class ArrayInputAggregator extends Aggregator[Array[String], Int, Int] with Serializable {

    override def zero = {0}

    override def reduce(buffer: Int, newItem: Array[String]): Int = {
      buffer + newItem.length
    }

    override def merge(b1: Int, b2: Int): Int = {
      b1 + b2
    }

    override def finish(reduction: Int): Int = reduction
    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
    def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
  }
}
```

I am testing it with this code:

```
val test = udaf(new ArrayInputAggregator())

val d = spark
      .sql("select array('asd','tre','asd') arr")
      .groupBy()
      .agg(test($"arr").as("cnt"))

d.show
```

This is the exception I am getting:

> 2023-12-24 12:06:24,678 ERROR spark.executor.Executor - Exception in
> task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.MapObjects$.apply(objects.scala:682)
> ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$applyOrElse$172$$anonfun$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:3033)
> ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveDeserializer$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$applyOrElse$172$$anonfun$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:3029)
> ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:309)
> ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
> ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]    at

(it goes on and on)

Comment: I can reproduce the described behavior for Spark 3.0.0, but it seems to be fixed for Spark 3.1.0 and later

Comment: Works fine for 3.4.1

Comment: Could be it was this [SPARK-32159](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32159)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this bug has been fixed in Spark 3.0.1 and higher.